# My generator works not the way I want him to. Looks like simple example, but dosnt work

Tags: javascript, function, generator, es6-modules, es6-module-loader

[Here is a pic of console log and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj5WW.png)

What it should do: takes a string and it should console.log separate words.
 What it does: it takes a string and console.log evry letter of it. And I dont understand why it does it. I'm returning the whole word with yield(I checked dst with console.log), so it should console.loged it, but in return it goes through evry letter(((( Thank you very much for your time!

scripts.js

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import  {wordsCount, getWords} from './other.js';

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
        let str = '  Its a  good weather! Yeah  ! ';  

        //console.log(wordsCount(str));

        let iterator = getWords(str);
for(let some of getWords(str)){                 
        this.console.log(some);                 
        }
});
```

other.js

```
function stringClear(str)
{
        return str.trim().replace(/ {2,}/, " ");
}

export function wordsCount(str){
        return stringClear(str).split(' ').length;
}

export function* getWords(str){
        str = stringClear(str);
        let dst = "";

        for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
        {
                if(str.charAt(i) == " ")
                {
                        yield* dst;
                        dst = "";
                        continue;
                }
                dst += str.charAt(i);
        }
}
```

console.log

```
I
scripts.js?6962:11 t
scripts.js?6962:11 s
scripts.js?6962:11 a
scripts.js?6962:11 g
2scripts.js?6962:11 o
scripts.js?6962:11 d
scripts.js?6962:11 w
scripts.js?6962:11 e
scripts.js?6962:11 a
scripts.js?6962:11 t
scripts.js?6962:11 h
scripts.js?6962:11 e
scripts.js?6962:11 r
scripts.js?6962:11 !
scripts.js?6962:11 Y
scripts.js?6962:11 e
scripts.js?6962:11 a
scripts.js?6962:11 h
```

Comment: Just take care of the formatting and the unnecessary code. It makes our job easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I thought maybe I should explain the `yield*` syntax better.  `yield*` will additionally iterate on the target yielded variable, yielding each value in the iterable.  eg:  `yield* [1,2,3,4,5]` will behave like: `yield 1; yield 2; yield 3; yield 4; yield 5`.  This is why when you do `yield* "abcd"` you are getting the equivalent of `yield "abcd"[0]; yield "abcd"[1]; yield "abcd"[2]; yield "abcd"[3]`

Extraneous asterisk in front of the yield.  You're yielding an iterator on the string you are yielding there, so each yield is additionally iterating on each word string before continuing after the yield*

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
        let str = '  Its a  good weather! Yeah  ! ';  

        //console.log(wordsCount(str));

        let iterator = getWords(str);
for(let some of getWords(str)){                 
        this.console.log(some);                 
        }
});

function stringClear(str)
{
        return str.trim().replace(/ {2,}/, " ");
}

function wordsCount(str){
        return stringClear(str).split(' ').length;
}

function* getWords(str){
        str = stringClear(str);
        let dst = "";

        for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
        {
                if(str.charAt(i) == " ")
                {
                        yield dst;

                        dst = dst.slice(dst.length);
                        
                        continue;
                }
                dst += str.charAt(i);
        }
}
```

Comment: You can accept an answer if it helps you to give the question closure

Answer (score 0):

Just change `yield* dst;` to `yield dst;` and it will be working.

I guess, that's by mistake.

But, if you happen to do it on purpose and didn't know the difference between the both, read this -
https://medium.com/dailyjs/a-simple-guide-to-understanding-javascript-es6-generators-d1c350551950